# When does $E=\frac{3}{2}pV$ hold?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

I only know that it holds for classical (monatomic) ideal gas and quantum ideal gas. But does it hold for interacting classical gas (e.g. van der Waals gas)?

Comment: It does not always hold for van der Waals (but can be a good approximation in some cases). For more info see the limitations to the [Equipartition theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equipartition_theorem#Limitations). See also [this note](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=BCuNTPO7A10C&pg=PA218&lpg=PA218&dq=Equipartition+theorem+van+der+waals&source=bl&ots=MAkNoMN3dF&sig=nd5FoiKsMdoLp6Q9-nZIK5seYfk&hl=no&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiT1aK4kIPNAhXlKsAKHRbLDrEQ6AEIOTAD#v=onepage&q=Equipartition%20theorem%20van%20der%20waals&f=false) for  an estimate for the degree of violation.